# R variable in single quoted "json" object for Elasticsearch query

Tags: json, r, elasticsearch

How do I put a variable inside an elasticsearch query body?

This is what I want:

```
a = "apple"
body = '{
         "query": {
             "match": {
                 "fruit": a
             }
         }
 }'
```

This is what I have, but it will be unreadable for large query bodies:

```
paste('{"query": {"match": {"fruit": "', a, '"}}}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `jsonlite` package with a list.

```
library(jsonlite)

a <- "apple"

body <- list(
  query = list(
    match = list(
      fruit = a
    )
  )
)

toJSON(body)

# {"query":{"match":{"fruit":["apple"]}}}
```

As suggested by [Rich Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/rich-scriven), you could add `pretty = TRUE` and/or `auto_unbox = TRUE` to the `toJSON` statement to alter the output.

`pretty = TRUE`

```
# {
#   "query": {
#     "match": {
#       "fruit": ["apple"]
#     }
#   }
# }
```

`auto_unbox = TRUE`

```
# {"query":{"match":{"fruit":"apple"}}}
```

All combinations are valid *JSON*

Comment: Very nice.  Could add `toJSON(body, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)` to get closer to OP's desired result.

Comment: R is pain. Thanks, @RichScriven and Kevin.